# interactive で数字をクエリする際に、デフォルト値を可能にするには？

Tags: elisp

elisp で関数を interactive 宣言して、数字の引数を取得する際に、デフォルト値を取れるようにしたいのですが、これは一般的にどう実現されますか？

例えば、次のような関数で

```
(defun num-square (n)
  (interactive "nNumber: ")
  (print (* n n)))
```

デフォルト値を取れるとは、何も入力せずに<kbd>RET</kbd>を入力された場合には、
既定の値がその引数に bind されるような挙動を期待しています。

Comment: `(interactive "n~")` とした場合、数値以外を入力すると `Please enter a number.` と表示されて再度の入力待ちになります。数値を入力するか `C-g(keyboard-quit)` を入力しない限り終了しません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read-number` 関数の説明文に、

> ```
> (read-number PROMPT &optional DEFAULT)
> ```
>
> Read a numeric value in the minibuffer, prompting with *PROMPT*. *DEFAULT* specifies a default value to return if the user just types RET. The value of *DEFAULT* is inserted into *PROMPT*. **This function is used by the 'interactive’ code letter ‘n’**.

とありますので、`read-number` を使うとデフォルト値を指定することが可能です(以下の例ではデフォルト値として `0` を指定)。

```
(defun num-square (n)
  (interactive (list (read-number "Number: " 0)))
  (prin1 (* n n)))
```

ただ、この場合は数値の入力に限定されますので、例えば文字列を入力する場合には `read-string` を使う必要があります。